# Joining two tables using third as linking table, including null entries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, ansi-sql

I've looked at a number of similar questions, but have yet to stumble upon/find the correct solution to the problem below.

Given the following three tables:

```
account
    profile_id number (nullable)
    bill_acct varchar
    status varchar (nullable)
    remarks varchar (nullable)


stage
    ecpd_profile_id number (nullable)
    bill_account varchar (nullable)
    account_class varchar (nullable)

profile
    ecpd_profile_id number
    reg_prof_id number
```

I need to create a join(s) to select the following:

```
account.bill_act, account.status, account.remarks, stage.account_class
```

where

```
profile.ecpd_profile_id = (given number)
```

`account.profile_id` and `profile.reg_prof_id` are equivalent

`stage.ecpd_profile_id` and `profile.ecpd_profile_id` are equivalent

`stage.bill_acct` and `account.bill_acct` are equivalent

I've tried the following...

```
select
    account.bill_acct,
    account.status,
    account.remarks,
    stage.account_class
from
    registration_account account
        join registration_profile profile
            on account.profile_id = profile.reg_prof_id
        join acct_stg stage
            on stage.ecpd_profile_id = profile.ecpd_profile_id
                and stage.bill_acct = account.bill_acct
where
    profile.ecpd_profile_id = ?
```

This works, but excludes all of the account entries for which there is no match in stage.

I need to have all rows of `account.bill_acct=stage.bill_acct`, appending an additional column for the `stage.account_class` where it exists, or null otherwise.

Multiple joins always throw me.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe that all you're looking for is a LEFT JOIN on stage instead of a regular (INNER) JOIN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try left join:

```
select
    account.bill_acct,
    account.status,
    account.remarks,
    stage.account_class
from
    registration_account account
    left join registration_profile profile
            on account.profile_id = profile.reg_prof_id
    left join acct_stg stage
            on stage.ecpd_profile_id = profile.ecpd_profile_id
                and stage.bill_acct = account.bill_acct
where
    profile.ecpd_profile_id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks, that (LEFT JOIN) was it.

Answer (score 3):

As you want to extract all the information independent on stage table(no matches on stage table), the best suitable to use `LEFT JOIN` in following way:

```
SELECT
    account.bill_acct,
    account.status,
    account.remarks,
    stage.account_class
FROM
    registration_account account
        JOIN registration_profile profile
            ON account.profile_id = profile.reg_prof_id
       LEFT JOIN acct_stg stage
            ON stage.ecpd_profile_id = profile.ecpd_profile_id
                and stage.bill_acct = account.bill_acct
WHERE
    profile.ecpd_profile_id = ?
```

`LEFT JOIN` returns all records from the left table or all record before `LEFT JOIN,` even if there are no matches in the right table.